# Insert String into Document with a specified font

Tags: java, swing, fonts, document

I know I can set a font family on an AttributeSet like this:

```
        SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(set, "Monospace");

        doc.insertString(
            caretPosition, text, set);
```

But what I really want to do is set a font:

```
        StyleConstants.setFont(set, "Courier New");
```

However, there is no StyleConstants.setFont() method.

So how do I set a font on an AttributeSet?  (Note that I am free to use an implementation of AttributeSet other than SimpleAttributeSet.  I just happened to use that one.)

(Note that my real goal is to insert a string into a Document using a specified font.)

Comment: Works fine for me. Post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resetting attributes in a Document after inserting a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955324/resetting-attributes-in-a-document-after-inserting-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set all font attributes using StyleConstants:

```
SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setFontFamily(set, "Monospace");
StyleConstants.setFontSize(set, 22);
StyleConstants.setBold(set, true);
StyleConstants.setItalic(set, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case the

```
SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setFontFamily(set, "Monospace");
```

does not work. I must change the "Monospace" to "Monospaced":

```
StyleConstants.setFontFamily(set, "Monospaced");
```

To find all available family you can use the following code:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
String[] fnt = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();

for (String f : fnt){
            System.out.println(f);
}
```

Benedek

Comment: Pretty useful.  Thanks